# How to detect when container embed UINavigationController pushes shows new view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created UIViewController (A) in storyboard and add container with UINavController.

Root of my embed UINavController is UIViewController (B) with button.

If I tap on the button, NavController shown new one UIViewController (C).

So I have UINavController -> B -> C. How can A-controller detect B -> C transition inside it's contained NavController?

Comment: make a protocol in UIViewController(B) and confirm it from UIViewController(A). Then call the delegate function from UIViewController(B) when you tap on the button on UIViewController(B)

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways you can do that but the simplest solution might be to use NotificationCenter. You listen for notification whenever it is posted, give it a unique name such as ViewA or ViewB notification then listen for a notification with that name. Check an example below: -

```
import UIKit

struct NotificationNames {
    static let bViewController
    static let cViewController
}



class AViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Listen for notification of from BViewcontroller
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didLoadBViewController), name: Notification.Name(NotificationNames.bViewController), object: nil)

        // Listen for notification of from CViewcontroller
           NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didLoadCViewController), name: Notification.Name(NotificationNames.cViewController), object: nil)

    }


    @objc private func didLoadBViewController() {
        print("B ViewController is loaded.")
    }

    @objc private func didLoadCViewController() {
           print("C ViewController is loaded.")
       }

    // Remove notification listeners to save some memory
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NotificationNames.bViewController, object: nil)
         NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NotificationNames.cViewController, object: nil)
    }

}


class BViewcontroller: UIViewController {

    // Post notification that B ViewController loaded.
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NotificationNames.bViewController, object: nil)
    }

}

class CViewController: UIViewController {

     // Post notification that C ViewController loaded.
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewDidAppear(true)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NotificationNames.cViewController, object: nil)
     }

}
```